# New Test App Build on iTunes 10 Won't Install

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, deployment

I have been developing test builds of an app for some time and have deployed through iTunes successfully until now, with iTunes 10.

At the same time I am getting a strange warning in Xcode during the build.  It is:

- warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2'.

My target SDK is 3.1.3, base is 3.2.  If I change the base to 4.0 the warning goes away.  In either case the app's .ipa is recognized by iTunes, accepted, asks if I want to replace the existing app in iTunes.  BUT, a synch does not move the app to the device, without any error or warnings.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can get iTunes to synch the app IF I delete the old one from iTunes first.  This is NOT desirable as each device's local user data is lost.  So it appears that iTunes does not replace its copy, even though it asks if it should.  Note the version has not been changed, though I never have changed it.

Comment: I can also get the new app on the device if I add to iTUnes, then delete the app from the device.  So apparently iTunes does hold the proper app version, but doesn't determine correct synch (or I don't understand the requirements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point iTunes has started requiring that the bundle version number be increased from the installed app.  Once I started doing this in the info.plist of the app, the installation proceeds as expected.

Answer (score 1):

SDK 3.2 if for iPad development (or for Universal apps).  For iPhone only use 4.0 (or maybe 4.1 tomorrow).

Comment: Switching to base of 4.0 removes the build warning, but still does not get the app onto a device (via iTunes).